# Should I use the class or instance method to increment my object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, increment, counter-cache

There are two methods to increment an attribute in Rails:

Instance-level: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!
Class-level: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment_counter/class

I want to update a counter attribute on my Post model that saves the number of comments for a post.

Is any of the two better for my use case?

I will use it with a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose, I think that you should use an attribute like `:counter_cache` in AR association. For example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # cached value will stored into the comments_count column at posts table
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

Rails will do a lot of work without your attention.

For two methods that you mentioned above (`increcement_counter` and `incresement`) they are use for different purposes. The `increcement_counter` is the back magic for `counter_cache`. The `incresement` use for just increase some integer value in the table.

Comment: Cool, I assume the type of the `counter_cache` column is `integer`?

Answer (score 0):

The instance ***#increment_counter***: more oop, and runs *#update_all*(fast and without validations).